# Resize and alter position property on scroll—at all scroll speeds—using jQuery

Tags: jquery, css, html, scroll, css-position

On page load, I have a large logo that (intentionally) overlaps the top navigation bar. My objective is to shrink it and move it up into the nav bar upon scroll, where it becomes a fixed element (and pops back out into the larger version when scrolling back to the top). My current code partially achieves this objective.

The problem is an inconsistency in execution depending on scrolling speed. While scrolling down at a slow rate, everything works as expected. But scrolling down quickly causes the logo to jump up into its final nav bar position before it has shrunk sufficiently. The logo moves up 19px (from 27 to 8), and is supposed to shrink from (300 x 111) to (100 x 37) from start to finish.

**jQuery**

```
/* Resize logo */
var scroll_pos = 0;
$(window).scroll(function() {
    scroll_pos = $(this).scrollTop();
    if ($(window).scrollTop() <= 19) {
        $(".logo").width(300 - 10.5263 * scroll_pos).height(111 - 3.8947 * scroll_pos);
    }
});
```

The scalar values I multiply `scoll_pos` by above are (300 - 100)/19 and (111 - 37)/19.

My guess is that scrolling quickly makes the function exit the condition before it has a chance to update the size. If that's the case, perhaps an entirely different approach will be necessary here?

```
/* Stick & unstick logo, adjust content */
var offset = $(".logo").offset();
$(window).scroll(function() {
    var scrollTop = $(window).scrollTop();
    if ((offset.top - 8) <= scrollTop) {
        $(".logo").addClass('fixed');
        $(".content").addClass('adjust');
    } else {
        $(".logo").removeClass('fixed');
        $(".content").removeClass('adjust');
    }
});
```

**Demo:**
http://jsfiddle.net/shimonoku/hfaeht2b/2/
 ←  in this demo, you'll notice a blue div named "target" in the nav bar—that's where the logo is supposed to end up (and does, when you scroll slow enough).

Comment: A simple solution would be to add an else-block which resizes the logo to it's final size. http://jsfiddle.net/hfaeht2b/4/

Comment: Thank you, @thykka! That was a much simpler solution than I expected.